# How to sort a list of dictionaries by length of dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries where each dictionary can have a different length (different number of keys). How can I sort my list so that the longest dictionary is at `list[0]`?

Comment: All the answers have worked correctly. I chose the one proposed by Dima Kudosh as it does not require a new list to be created to store the sorted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sort method in your list:

```
list_with_dicts.sort(key=lambda x: -len(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

Sort the list with `key=len`

```
>>> d0
{'a': 100, 'c': 150, 'b': 5, 'd': 60}
>>> d1
{1: 'ONE', 2: 'TWO'}
>>> d2
{3: 'THREE', 4: 'FOUR'}
>>> d3
{1:'ONE',2:'TWO',3:'THREE'}
l = [d0,d1,d2,d3]
>>> sorted(l, key=len, reverse=True)
[{'a': 100, 'c': 150, 'b': 5, 'd': 60}, {1: 'ONE', 2: 'TWO', 3: 'THREE'}, {1: 'ONE', 2: 'TWO'}, {3: 'THREE', 4: 'FOUR'}]
>>>
>>> l.sort(key=len, reverse=True) #in list sorting
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass to `sorted` `key` parameter with length of your dicts:

```
sorted_list = sorted(l, key = lambda x: len(x.keys())
```

Or just

```
sorted_list = sorted(l, key = len)
```

Where `l` is a list with your dicts

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` method:

```
newList = sorted(list, key=lambda k:len(k), reverse = True)
```

or without create a new list:

```
list = sort(key=lambda k:len(k), reverse = True)
```